# How do I reload my TortoiseSVN's Settings after making modifications to its config file on Windows?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have made some changes to `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion\config` file. And I want to make the modifications work.

How do I reload them by not restarting the whole system?

Comment: Make them through the TortoiseSVN settings dialog, which reloads them when you save. Otherwise, restarting the system is probably the only way to have them take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need restart your machine after modifying Subversion's runtime configuration. Changes to `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Subversion\config` are effective immediately after you save the file.

If your modifications don't work, I suggest verifying whether they are valid (e.g. check the syntax).

See [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html).